# How can I do this ForEach using lambda?

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I have this `foreach` that parses some class to another:

```
public static List<MyClassParsed> getMyParsed(List<MyClassResponse> responses) {

    List<MyClassParsed> parses = new ArrayList<>();

    for (MyClassResponse response : responses) {

        var parse = MyClassParsed.builder()
                .id(response.getId())
                .name(response.getName())
                .build();

        parses.add(parse);
    }

    return detalhes;
}
```

I mean, can I do this using something like `responses.stream().foreach(...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're transforming a list to a list of objects derived from elements of that list, so `map` looks like a good solution.

```
public static List<MyClassParsed> getMyParsed(List<MyClassResponse> responses) {
    return responses.stream()
                    .map(r -> 
                         MyClassParsed
                             .builder()
                             .id(r.getId())
                             .name(r.getName())
                             .build())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your list to another using different lambda features:

One line:

```
List<MyClassParsed> parses = responses.stream().map(response -> MyClassParsed.builder().id(response.getId()).name(response.getName()).build()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Method reference:

```
public class Mapper {
    static MyClassParsed map(MyClassResponse response) {
       return MyClassParsed.builder().id(response.getId()).name(response.getName()).build();
    }
    public void getMyParsed(List<MyClassResponse> responses) {
        List<MyClassParsed> parses = responses.stream().map(Mapper::map).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Function instance:

```
 Function<MyClassResponse, MyClassParsed> mapper = response -> MyClassParsed.builder().id(response.getId()).name(response.getName()).build();
 List<MyClassParsed> parses = responses.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
```